# Iplementing a stack using 2 queues

Tags: python, stack, queue, implementation

This is a homework question and I don't know if my code is right or wrong. Question: How can I print the stack (hence know if the code is working or not)? If wrong, what should I change.

What I have:

```
class stack:

    def __init__(self):
        self.q1 = []
        self.q2 = []

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.size()==0
    def pop(self):
        return self.q1.pop(0)
    def push(self, item):
        self.q2.append(item)
        for i in range (len(self.q1)):
            self.q2.append(self.q1.pop)
        self.q2 = self.q1
        print (self.q1)


s = stack()
s.push('2')
print (s)
```

Comment: Your code is definitely not working, as `isEmpty` will cause `AttributeError` due to the absence of the `size` method. In terms of printing the stack, implement `__str__` and `__repr__`.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I print the stack?

Well, there's one obvious possibility, which doesn't depend on your implementation at all (which makes it a great unit test): Just look around `s.pop()` until it fails:

```
while True:
    try:
        print(s.pop())
    except IndexError:
        break
```

---

But what if you want to test non-destructively? Well, there are two options there.

---

First, staying with the "black box" approach, if you assume that `push` works properly, you can take advantage of the invariants of what a stack is supposed to do to print out the stack while building a copy:

```
s2 = stack()
while True:
    try:
        value = s.pop()
    except IndexError:
        break
    else:
        print(value)
        s2.push(value)
```

Of course that gives you a reversed stack, so you'll want to loop over that again, reversing `s2` back into `s`:

```
while True:
    try:
        value = s2.pop()
        s.push(value)
    except IndexError:
        break
```

---

Second, you can switch to a white-box approach. What does `pop` do? Well, it returns the last value in `q1`, and removes it. So, if you call `pop` repeatedly, it's just going to return the values in `q1` in reverse order. So:

```
for value in reversed(s.q1):
    print(value)
```

---

But if you run any of these, you're going to see that the stack is always empty. Why? Well, let's look at your `push`:

```
def push(self, item):
    self.q2.append(item)
    for i in range (len(self.q1)):
        self.q2.append(self.q1.pop)
```

OK, the first problem is here: you forgot to *call* `pop` here, so you're just appending the method `self.q1.pop` itself, rather than popping a value and appending the result.

```
    self.q2 = self.q1
```

And here, you've done all this work to move all the values from `q1` to `q2`, and then you replace `q2`—which has all your values—with `q1`—which is empty.

But, even if you fix that, what is `q1` actually doing? It's always empty at the start. It's always empty after a `push`. It's always shorter after a `pop`. So it can't possibly ever have anything in it. So clearly, you have a fundamental problem with your design, and there's no way to fix the implementation of a broken design.